# Magento 2 copy SKU value to custom attribute value

Tags: product, product-attribute, custom-attributes, magento2.3.1

I have approx 50000 product in my store. I would like to copy the SKU value to the Custom attribute(custom_sku_field) value for all products.

I think going for SQL query might be risky. so can anyone suggest the programmatically way to update custom attribute value for all products?

I have tried these solutions but it's not working
[Refrance 1](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/15960/how-to-copy-a-products-attributes-value-to-another-attribute-in-magento)
[Refrance 2](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/54396/how-to-copy-a-products-attributes-value-to-another-attribute)

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: why dont you simply download all products in CSV and copy SKU column with your new attribute code name in a new column and upload that CSV, rather than programming ? just a thought

Comment: It's a 50k product do you really think need to update using CSV? it is too time-consuming.

Comment: I personally think updating via programming will be more time consuming, as you will have to get individual product object, and set the value and save it again, though import is doing the same thing internally, but it will be more systematic as compared to custom programming, as both the references you mentioned are loading product and then setting attribute value and saving it.